# Why is there a huge difference between Is2(peak) and Is2(rms) in flyback converter?

Tags: transformer, flyback

I try to design a flyback converter which has two outputs.
First output is main output **24V/1A** and second output is for Vcc **18V/0,02A**.

Total output power -> Po = 24,4W
Efficiency = 85%
So, input power -> Pin = 28,7W
Input voltage is changeable -> VminDC = 70V & VmaxDC = 140V

PWM frequency -> fs = 470kHz
Reflected output voltage -> Vro = 48V
[image]
Calculated Dmax = 46%

I selected ripple factor -> Krf = 0,5 for **CCM**
[image]
Primary inductance -> Lm = 60µH

Because of this inductance value;
[image]

[image]

Problem begins here.

When I tyr to calculate secondary peak and rms value, I'm getting some **results that I don't understand**.

- Turn ratio for main output (Is1) (24V/1,5A) = 2:1
- turn ratio for Vcc output (Is2) (18V/0,02A) = 2,7:1

Ip(peak) = 1,51A
So
Is1(peak) = Ip(peak) x Np/Ns1
IS2(peak) = Ip(peak) x Np/Ns2
Is1(peak) = 1,51 x 2 = 3,02A ( output current is 1A )
Is2(peak) = 1,51 x 2,7 = 4,03A ( output current is **0,02A** )

[image]

What does it mean?
There is a **huge difference** between Is2(peak) and Is2(rms), although the Is1(peak) and Is1(rms) values are **close to each other**.

How can I calculate the secondary peak and rms current in generally. What is wrong thing here?

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are doing a calculation which has any actual meaning, more than you've just grabbed some numbers from different places and thrown them together.  How about editing this to explain exactly what calculation you are doing and why you believe it meaningfully represents an aspect of the circuit.

Comment: Your calculation still doesn't make any sense.  Where does the 1.52 come from and why do you believe what you are doing with it is going to yield anything of meaning?

Comment: How can total output power be 24,4 watts when it's clearly at least 36 watts.

Comment: This is very hard to follow.  Is it possible to link to where you got your formulas?  And remove Edit and correct question with correct numbers.  We are not correcting your work, but will try to help you.

Comment: I used the application note of OnSemi called AN-4137 and prepared a calculator by Excel. I tested my calculator with values at this app note. But, there are some points that I don't understand. I could share it, but it is Turkish. I must translate it

Comment: Your calculation for main secondary is correct, yet the calculation of Vcc winding's peak current is wrong. Because the energy stored by the primary is not transferred to this winding. At least, not completely: a small percentage which can be neglected is transferred to Vcc winding. Remember E=0.5 × L × I².

Comment: Ok, how can I calculate the secondary peak and rms current in generally. Is1(peak) is true but İs2(peak) is wrong. Why? What is true calculation method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did I get it right?
[image]

Can I calculate **real** Isx(peak) by calculation above.

So, do I have to calculate the solution **based on energy**?

Answer (score 1):

As you might already know the primary winding *(actually, its magnetic field)* stores energy during the primary switch remains on:

$$
E=0.5\ L_p\ I_{p-pk}^2
$$

And, this energy will be transferred *(partially or completely, depending on the operations mode -- DCM or CCM)* to secondary/secondaries once the primary switch opens.

> IS2(peak) = Ip(peak) x Np/Ns2

Technically the formula assumes that all the energy is transferred to this winding (i.e. Vcc winding). But this is not what actually happens because the Vcc winding does not consume all the energy that is stored by the primary. Its requirement is about 1% of the total. That's why it's almost always neglected. But,

> Is1(peak) = Ip(peak) x Np/Ns1

This is correct. Because 99% of the total energy is consumed by this main secondary. Check the power ratings of the secondaries: 18 × 0.02 = 360mW for Vcc, and 24V × 1.5 = 36W for main secondary.

Remember that we almost always neglect the power consumption of the Vcc winding. Because it really does not make much difference: ~36.4W against 36W.

PS: I personally recommend you to study switching power supplies from these two books: [Switching Power Supply Design](https://www.amazon.com.tr/Switching-Power-Supply-Design-3rd/dp/0071482725/) from A. Pressman, and [Switchmode Power Supply Handbook](https://www.amazon.com.tr/Switchmode-Power-Supply-Handbook-3/dp/0071639713/) from K. Billings.

Comment: I have answered for this post. But, it is seeming top on this post